# PHP: adding prices to a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to edit my PHP script so the prices I have added to the form will be added as a total when the user clicks submit but I am not sure how to add up the values.

HTML

```
<select name="service">
<option value="Yes" value="10">Yes £10</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<form method="post" action="example.php">
<select name="booking">
<option value="Double Room" value="50">Double Room £50</option>
<option value="Twin Room" value="70">Twin Room £70</option>
<option value="Family Room" value="100">Family room £100</option>
</select>
<br /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" action="example.php" name="submit"><br />
</form>
```

PHP

```
You have choosen the <?php echo $_POST["booking"]; ?>
```

Comment: Added with what ? Previous value ?

Comment: didn't get you? what you want to add? with what?

Comment: also, you have 2 "value" parameters for each of your options...

Comment: sorry, I ment prices. For example the double room costs £50. So when the form is submitted it will show the total as which ever room has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You're defined twice the `value` attribute of the `options` tags and this is an *error*.

If you want to access the price, just set the price as a single `value` attribute.

A better way would be to identify each row with an ID and having a corresponding array in PHP to get both the name and the price (either as an array again, or better as an object).

Hope it helps